# Erro no metodo remover o final de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x

```
esta dando erro no setProx(None) alguem pode ajudar ?

  def removeFinal(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
        print("Impossivel Remover Lista Vazia")
        ultimoValorNo = self.ultimoNo.getElemento()
    if self.primeiroNo is self.ultimoNo:
        self.primeiroNo = self.ultimoNo = None
    else:
        noAtual = self.primeiroNo
        while noAtual.getProx() != self.ultimoNo:
            noAtual = noAtual.getProx()
            noAtual.setProx(None)
            self.ultimoNo = noAtual
    return ultimoValorNo
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma lista encadeada correto? A indentação está incorreta, perceba que no else você está executando a exclusão mesmo que a condição `noAtual.getProx() != self.ultimoNo` seja verdadeira.

```
def removeFinal(self):
  if self.isEmpty():
      print("Impossivel Remover Lista Vazia")
      ultimoValorNo = self.ultimoNo.getElemento()
  if self.primeiroNo is self.ultimoNo:
      self.primeiroNo = self.ultimoNo = None
  else:
      noAtual = self.primeiroNo
      while noAtual.getProx() != self.ultimoNo:
          noAtual = noAtual.getProx()
      noAtual.setProx(None)
      self.ultimoNo = noAtual
  return ultimoValorNo
```